# looking for a demo of CHIPS cookie in action

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, setcookie, chips, partitioned

Chrome is planning to restrict support for 3rd party cookies further starting in 2024.
https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/blog/cookie-countdown-2023oct

this means we need to use the CHIPS approach https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd/chips
(in short, 3rd parties cookies will be associated not to 3rd-party domain but a combination of origin and 3rd-party domain to guarantee it can't be used from any other origin)
and for browser to support that we need to add Partitioned; attribute to our cookies.

My question is that,
is there any demo/sample site that can demonstrates this CHIPS approach in action?
And is there any chrome extension that allows me to add this property and quickly test my situation (I tried multiple chrome extensions but when I modify the cookie by adding Partitioned property, the cookie disappears !)

My situation is that I have a user logged into two sites (say Site A and B) using OAuth/OpenID Connect.
Some JS code that is running on Site A makes a fetch call to a protected endpoint on Site B and necessary cookies are being sent by the browser (I'm using credentials: "include").
So far everything works fine but If I enable the new [restriction](https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/blog/cookie-countdown-2023oct#test) in my chrome then it no longer sends the cookie.
I want to know if I can fix this by simply adding Partitioned; property in my set-cookie header or that also I have to pop an iframe of Site B inside Site A for the partitioned cookie to be set picked up by the browser and only after that I would be able to make JS fetch. If that's the case; it looks like a messy solution. and I wonder if there is better approach?

Comment: yeah, more examples would be very helpful...